# Image rollover flicker using images via css in Safari

Tags: css, image, safari, hover, rollover

I have a fairly image heavy site and have image rollovers (:hover) on a lot of images on the page. The page loads but the rollovers images take longer to load and cause a flickering when the user intially rolls over the image. I know that this issue has been disscussed many times however I have not found an appropriate solution that works.

I am using safari, background rollovers are done through css. Need some kind of hover image preloader or delay script or similar but any suggestion is welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [CSS Sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).  That's the time-tested, tried and true technique for avoiding flicker like this on hovers.